# Inline checkbox next to a h3 header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a simple checkbox inline to the left of a header, i've tried to add the inline css as below but it still does align.

```
 <input type="checkbox" style="display:inline"/><h3>Header Text</h3>
```

I have a list that i would like the user to select, hence why i would like  checkbox next to each one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The h3 element is a block element by default (i.e. 100% width, so it won't fit anything else on that line)

Alter it to inline-block and you'll see that it should work fine (it also means that you can remove the inline styling of the checkbox, as well):

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<h3>Header Text</h3>
```

Answer (score -1):

`h3` tag takes whole width you have to set the CSS style to `h3` no need to set for checkbox.

The following code will help you

```
<input type="checkbox"/><h3 style="display:inline">Header Text</h3>
```

Comment: Please format code blocks either (a) by adding 4 spaces in front or (b) selecting the code block and doing Ctrl + K or (c) selecting the code block and clicking the `{}` icon in the tool bar.

Comment: Sorry I forgot in a curry. Thanks